# How can be forbidden to use some methods from superclass for some objects?

Tags: java

I have staff as an object. Each staff can be either manager or attendent!

It dependents on value one variable int status

I would make superclass for manager. How can be forbidden to use attendent methods from superclass?

Comment: Could you please show us your codes ?

Comment: *"How can be forbidden to use attendent methods from superclass?"* The superclass `Staff` doesn't know the methods added by subclass `Attendant`, so there is no need to forbid anything.

Comment: If you make some class a superclass of manager, it will also be superclass  of attendent. A superclass can not access methods of its subclasses so if this is what you are saying,there is no risk of it.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like this is what you want:

Super class: `Staff.java`

Two sub classes: `Manager extends Staff` and `Attendant extends Staff` - `Manager.java` and `Attendant.java`.

`Manager` and `Attendant` are two different java classes/files. They're not related in a hierarchy. So there is no risk for the `Attendant` using something from `Manager`.

There is only a risk of a sub-class using something from the super-class if there is a hierarchy. Your question doesn't make clear what hierarchy you are concerned with.

Answer (score 0):

The methods of subclass are not visible to superclass so if you make some superclass for manager, there is no chance that the superclass can see the methods of both manager and attendent. Hence no need to forbid anything.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mean you will create a `Manager` **subclass** of class `Staff`.

You should implement your `Manager`-specific methods in the `Manager` class, and then **override the 'not allowed methods' providing a dummy implementation** e.g. `return null;` or `throw new ActionNotSupported();`.

E.g.

```
public class Manager extends Staff {
    public void manage() {
        //OK the manager can manage... provide an implementation
    }

    @Override
    public void pickUpHeavyThings() {
        // The manager cannot do that... (no offence) so:
        throw new InvalidActionException();
    }
}
```

EDIT

The best solution of course would be to refactor your code and create another subclass for `Attendant` moving there the functionality from the `Staff` superclass level. So, an object would instantiate either `Attendant` or `Manager`, and it will have available only its specific methods. At the `Staff` class level (which should be abstract) there should only remain the general-purpose methods e.g.

```
public abstract class Staff {
    public void getPaid() {
        // everybody can do this
    }

    public void goForLunch() {
        // everybody can do this - if he wants
    }
}
```

And then:

```
public class Manager extends Staff {
    public void manage() {
        //OK the manager can manage... provide an implementation
    }
}
```

And:

```
public class Attendant extends Staff {
    public void pickUpHeavyThings() {
        // OK, the attendant can do this... provide an implementation
    }
}
```